# C++, comparing string in lines

Tags: c++, text, compare, lines

I need to check if my variable exist in specific place in each line in text file and if its same as in line.

lines in my text example:

```
one two variable 11 221
123 t12 variable 11 331
123 t12 bad_var  11 331
```

i want to check if the `variable` exist in line at place from `9 to 16` in line.
My code:

```
std::ifstream my_text_file("text_file.txt");
std::string str
if(my_text_file)
    {
     while(std::getline(my_text_file,str))
         {
          if(my_text_file.seekg(9,std::ios::beg))
             { //what should i wrote here?//   }
         }
    }
```

EDIT:

My `variable` its string looking like `abc3` , how can i choose only first 3 letters to compare from my variable like `abc` ?
   Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `seekg`? Read a line, then use `substr()` to get the part of the line you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be easiest to read the entire line into a string and then check for `variable` at the correct position within the string using [`substr()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).

```
std::getline(my_text_file, str);
std::string var = "variable";
if (str.substr(9, var.size()) == var) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Second argument to `substr` is the length, not the end position.

Comment: so its enought to show only when string starts and .end its not neccessary anymore?  Could You also tell me how to choose only 3 letters from my variable? normaly my `variable='abc3'` but i want to compare only `abc` Thanks!

Comment: You could use substr again. `str = "abc3"` and then do `str.substr(0, 3)` to get the first three characters of `str`

Comment: @ConfusedByCode  to it would be like: `if (str.substr(9, var.size()) == var.substr(0,3))` ?

Comment: Almost but not quite. The left hand side is still checking for a string that is as long as `var`, but on the right hand side you are only using the first 3 characters of `var`. The left hand side would need to be changed to `str.substr(9, 3)` so that the lengths of each string match.

Comment: Or better still, do `var = var.substr(0, 3)` first. Then  the line `str.substr(9, var.size()) == var)` does not need to change

Comment: @ConfusedByCode Thanks !